# Install MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, mysql

How to install the MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 10.04?

apt-get install mysql-server is only allows to install 5.1.41.3ubuntu12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have some specific problems with your environment or installation procedure, it follows the normal pattern:

- you should obtain the generic binary `.tar.gz` package from [MySql's download page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.5.html)
- then follow the [binary installation instructions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-installation.html)

Answer (score 5):

I used The following guide to install 5.5 on Ubuntu 10.04: http://www.ovaistariq.net/490/a-step-by-step-guide-to-upgrading-to-mysql-5-5/

Everything worked perfectly except one of the final steps, launching mysql:

```
mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql
```

Was giving me the following message and then shutting down:

```
[ERROR] Can't find messagefile '/usr/share/errmsg.sys'
```

After some [googling](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=mysql%20%22%5BERROR%5D%20Can%27t%20find%20messagefile%20%27/usr/share/errmsg.sys%27%22) I found the [solution to be adding the following flag](http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2010/09/30/#ubuntu-server.txt):

```
--lc-messages-dir="/usr/local/mysql/share/english/"
```

To launch it and have it actually work, I used the following command:

```
 mysqld --skip-grant-tables --user=mysql --lc-messages-dir="/usr/local/mysql/share/english/"
```

MySQL 5.5 has some great new features that solved a partitioning issue for me; partitioning via a varchar.

Good luck!

Comment: I was able to follow the instruction guide without any error. The only thing is at step "Start MySQL server without grants table." it looks like it hangs but it doesn't. Just open another terminal and continue the steps in that new terminal.

Answer (score 2):

```
add-apt-repository ppa:internetbroadcasting/mysql55onlucid
apt-get install mysql-server-5.5
```

Users with local apache+php5+mysql or similar combination with mysql in it would likely need to recompile mysql-dependent packages (php5-mysql), so it uses libmysqlclient18 provided by mysql-server-5.5.

Using libmysqlclient16-linked packages with mysql 5.5 installation might appear to be working initially, but would tend to crash randomly.

Comment: Don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Due to dependencies, I needed to run: `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5 mysql-client-5.5`

Answer (score 1):

simple instructions for installation of MySQL 5.5 on Linux are documented here along with other libraries that are required.

http://www.geeksww.com/tutorials/database_management_systems/mysql/installation/download_configure_compile_and_install_mysql_558_on_linux.php

Comment: Please summarize the steps here, rather than only plugging your own blog?

Answer (score 0):

I have written an article on how to install MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu 10.10 using Ubuntu packages, I'm pretty sure it will work without any major issues on 10.04: http://geek.co.il/wp/2011/03/02/mysql-5-5-on-ubuntu-10-10